# Is there any way to disable bind events on a component currently transitioning out with react spring?

Tags: react-spring

I'm using a spring (for dragging) inside a react-spring transition event. If i catch the object with the mouse while transitioning out, it breaks the animation. I do want to keep this for entering objects, but want to disable this for exiting objects. That is to say i want to disable drag while it's exiting. Is this possible?

Ideally I would want to write something like this:

```
const transitions = useTransition(reviews.carousel[0], {
...
onLeave: (_res, _spring, item) => {
  item.ignorePointer = true  
})
```

and then use that value to disable touch events.

Some problems with this:

- setting item.ignorePointer will not update state
- how to figure out if it changed since this does not work:

  ```
    onStart: (_res, _spring, item) => {
      let { carousel } = reviews
      if (carousel[0]._id !== item._id) {
        console.log('is leaving')
      }
    },
  ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about putting `pointer-event: none` style to the exiting element?

Comment: Updated the question with some more information. This is not really a css issue.